# Received memory warning when running UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am now develop an Iphone app which required user login Facebook and pass their data to webService and login to my game. Basically my game is run by HTML and it will display by UIWebView in my app.

Here is my codes to load webView:

```
-(void)callWebView {
self.webView.delegate = self;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.my_game_url"];
NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:requestURL];
}

-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
NSURL *url = request.URL;
NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;

if ( [ urlString isEqualToString: @"http://my_game_logout_url" ] ) {

    [myWebView stopLoading];
    [self.webView removeFromSuperview];

    MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [appDelegate.session closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    [FBSession.activeSession close];

    NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (cookie in [storage cookies]) {
        [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    return NO;
    }
return YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
[self.webView stopLoading];

MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[appDelegate.session closeAndClearTokenInformation];
[FBSession.activeSession close];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
webView.delegate = nil;
[webView stopLoading];
}

- (void)dealloc {
[webView setDelegate:nil];
}
```

It is fine to running my game with UIWebView. The problem is I will **receive memory warning** later, and my app will crash. I have to enable Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) to automatic release some sources which is no needed, but I will still received memory warning in my app. Have anything I implementing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Use Allocations in Instruments + heapshots => http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/03/08/using-heapshots-to-find-abandoned-memory.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your HTML game has no memory leaks by using desktop web browsers. Chrome Developer Tools is a convenient tools for the purpose. The javascript engine used by UIWebView has poor performance, you should optimize your game carefully.
2. Try [self.webView _setDrawInWebThread:YES]; after creating an UIWebView. It's a private API that capable of saving UIWebView's CPU and memory usage. But your app maybe rejected by App Store.

   SEL sel1 = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", @"_setDr", @"awInWebTh", @"read:"]);

   objc_msgSend(self.webView, sel1, YES);

will help.